# How to create regex to test for a number in an expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an email regex that looks like this:

```
var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
```

How can I update this regex to make at least 1 digit, at least 1 letter and a point (`.`) required?

```
bert@gmail.com INVALID 
111@22 INVALID 
craig11@gmail.com VALID
```

Comment: Any own research?

Comment: Also, WHY would you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use regex to match e.g allowed words `[a-zA-Z]` and digits `\d` or `[0-9]` to match e-mail adresses with at least one digit and one character as such:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\d.+)
```

which only matches craig11@gmail.com because it fulfils the criteria.

Or to go further, use word boundaries to demand @ and ., such as:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\d+\b@.+\b.+)
```

If you wish to match letters and digits after the @, you can use:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\d+\b@.+[a-zA-Z0-9]\b.+)
```

Test it out yourself on http://rubular.com/.

Comment: When I get ed@mail2.com I get not matched? I tried 'ed@mail2.com'

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a matching regex for your request.